# Supressing ServiceStack log messages using NLogFactory

Tags: servicestack, nlog

I am using NLog with ServiceStack and am having difficulty turning off the logs it generates. My NLog configuration is as follows:

```
<logger name="ServiceStack.*" minLevel="Off" writeTo="file" final="true"/>
<logger name="*" minLevel="Info" writeTo="file"/>
```

Basically what this should do is not log anything generated by SS and for everything else, only log things at the info level or below.

SS seems to be ignoring these settings though and is happily logging away. However, If I do the logging myself and grab a logger from the SS namespace, like

```
LogManager.LogFactory.GetLogger("ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceController")
    .Debug("Log Message at Debug Level");
```

it does obey the NLog configuration. It seems as if only the internal logs are ignoring the configuration. Is there something I am missing, or am I not doing it the correct way?